# The variable assigned is not globally changed after ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In this page I have a table with pagination. In the pagination section, the '' with class "first" display the first page record, class "last" last page, class "next" display next following data. These all function are working properly. But my problem is When I click the '' with class 'last', it is displaying the last page record. After that when I click the 'td' with class 'previous' it must display those records just before the last one.

E.g. if there are 17 pages and if I click the last then it is showing the 17 th page but when I click 'previous' it must show 16 not other.

So what I tried is update the page number after ajax success but this value is not changing globally in the page.

Can anybody help me with this. Thank you.

Below are my codes.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <table id="display_result">
        </table>
        <table id="pagination">
            <tr>
                <td><div class="first">|&lt;</div></td>
                <td><div class="previous">&lt;</div></td>
                <td><div class="next">&gt;</div></td>
                <td><div class="last">&gt;|</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

$(function(){
    var page;

    function displayData(ip, page, isLast){
        var input = ip;
        var datas = {
            'input': input,
            'page':page,
            'isLast':isLast
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "getData.php",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var response = data.result;
                page = data.page;
                $("#display_result").html('');
                $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                    $('<tr>').html(
                        "<td>" + response[i].line + "</td></tr>").appendTo('#display_result');
                });
            },
            async:false,
            data: datas
        });
    }

    $("#pagination").delegate('td div', 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filename = $('#myInput').val().split('\\');
        if ($(this).hasClass("first")){
            page = 0;
            displayData(filename[2], page, false);
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass("previous")){
            page = page - 1;
            displayData(filename[2], page, false);
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass("next")){
            page = page + 1;
            displayData(filename[2], page, false);
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass("last")){
            displayData(filename[2], page, true);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: So what do you get when you click previous?

Comment: @AmrAly    when i console here $("#pagination").delegate('td div', 'click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); console.log("start", page); I get '-1' which I think should be '17' according to my example

Comment: try `displayData(filename[2], page, true);` instead of `displayData(filename[2], page, false);` and tell me what you get.

Comment: When passed true, I get value '0'. This true and false I used to check if page is last or not

Comment: My problem will solve if I get the updated page inside delegate click function from ajax success

Comment: Why don't u initialize the `var page` as an object since the object is referenced type so it's value will be reflected immediately.

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: try `var page = { page : 0 }` and when u want to access the page number you can do that using this syntax `page.page` i know it's a little bit confusing but give it a shot and tell me what u get .

Comment: I didnot find any change

Comment: Mmm, have you tried to console the `page` variable inside `success` function to see if  its value is correct

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by adding a new function

```
function set_page(val){
    page = val;
}
```

then on ajax success, I pass a updated page

```
page = data.page;
set_page(page);
```

This solved for me.

Comment: Create a new function and change the value of the page on ajax success